# Calculate days between period with another time period

Tags: python, database, data-analysis

I'm trying to analyse data with a time period and want to set this in relation with a calender.

Data:
01-15-2021 | 02-17-2021 | Mike | service
03-12-2021 | 03-12-2021 | Tod  | installation
01-04-2021 | 01-17-2021 | Ron  | service
....

Now i want to know e.g. how many days from 01-05-2021 to 02-30-2021 were service and how many in Jan and Feb.

Don't know where to beginn oir what should i'm looking for.

Comment: I think learning the pandas library for data manipulation would be a good start.  It has very simple and useful datetime functionality.  Alternatively the datetime library in python can at least answer the time delta problem.  In any case you should write some basic code to read the data, and what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the number of days for each month in a dictionary. From there you can find the difference between the two dates, then calculate how many days in each month. Let's use the first row as an example:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt


# Number of days for each month from January to Jume
month_dict = {
    1: 30,
    2: 28,
    3: 31,
    4: 30,
    5: 31,
    6: 30
}
start_date = dt.strptime('01-15-2021', '%m-%d-%Y')
end_date = dt.strptime('02-17-2021', '%m-%d-%Y')

result = end_date - start_date
days_serviced = result.days - 1
days_in_january = month_dict[start_date.month] - start_date.day
days_in_february = end_date.day
print(days_serviced, 'days were serviced')
print(days_in_january, 'days in January')
print(days_in_february, 'days in Ferbuary')
```

output:

```sh
>>> 32 days were serviced
>>> 15 days in January
>>> 17 days in Ferbuary
```

By the way if you don't know about the datetime module, you can read more on it from this link https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime